# org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, apache, apache-poi

I have gone through all the other question on this topic and none of them worked for me. I would like to read .xlsx file in android version 4.0 and above, so please suggest solution accordingly.  I'm using `Android Studio 2.2.3` and **trying to read .xlsx file** .[image]

Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button writeExcelBtn,readExcelBtn;
public static final String appName =  "ReadXL";
public static final String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/"+"Download"+"/";
ArrayList<TokenDetailsModel> modelArrayList;
RecyclerView xlDataList;
XLDataListAdapter xlDataListAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    writeExcelBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.writeExcel);
    readExcelBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.readExcel);
    modelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    xlDataList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.data_list);

    xlDataList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));


    readExcelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            readExcelFile(MainActivity.this,"all_tokens.xlsx");

        }
    });

}

private void readExcelFile(Context context, String filename) {
    modelArrayList.clear();
    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly())
    {
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Storage not available or read only");
        return;
    }

    try{
        // Creating Input Stream
        //File file = new File(imagePath, filename);
        File file = new File(imagePath+filename);
        System.out.println("********** file path : "+imagePath+filename);
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Create a POIFSFileSystem object
        //POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

        // Create a workbook using the File System
        // HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
        XSSFWorkbook myBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
        // Get the first sheet from workbook
        //HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myBook.getSheetAt(0);

        /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
        Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
        // Iterator<Column> columnIterator = mySheet.iterator();
        TokenDetailsModel model = null;
        while(rowIter.hasNext()){
            model = new TokenDetailsModel();
            //HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow)rowIter.next();

            Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                //HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                Cell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();

                System.out.println("************ myCell.getRowIndex() and its data : "+myCell.getRowIndex()+"  "+myCell.toString());
                switch (myCell.getCellType()){
                    case CELL_TYPE_STRING :
                        System.out.println("************ string data :  "+myCell.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"String data : "+myCell.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC : System.out.println("************ string data :  "+myCell.getNumericCellValue());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"String data : "+myCell.getNumericCellValue(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                  /*  case 2 :model.setToken(myCell.toString());

                        break;

                    case 3 : model.setPhone1(myCell.toString());
                        break;

                    case 4 : model.setPhone2(myCell.toString());
                        break;*/

                }

                Log.w("FileUtils", "Cell Value: " +  myCell.toString());
                // Toast.makeText(context, "cell Value: " + myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           // modelArrayList.add(model);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("********** file exception : "+e);
    }

    /*xlDataListAdapter = new XLDataListAdapter(MainActivity.this,modelArrayList);
    xlDataList.setAdapter(xlDataListAdapter);*/
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Here is my log :

> 01-06 15:06:51.570 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   01-06 15:06:51.605 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
>   01-06 15:06:51.605 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:426)
>   01-06 15:06:51.610 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:431)
>   01-06 15:06:51.610 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
>   01-06 15:06:51.610 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:221)
>   01-06 15:06:51.610 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at com.etaserve.readxlsx.MainActivity.readExcelFile(MainActivity.java:83)
>   01-06 15:06:51.610 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at com.etaserve.readxlsx.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:29)
>   01-06 15:06:51.615 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at com.etaserve.readxlsx.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
>   01-06 15:06:51.615 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
>   01-06 15:06:51.615 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
>   01-06 15:06:51.615 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   01-06 15:06:51.615 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   01-06 15:06:51.615 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>   01-06 15:06:51.615 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>   01-06 15:06:51.620 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-06 15:06:51.620 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   01-06 15:06:51.620 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   01-06 15:06:51.620 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>   01-06 15:06:51.620 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-06 15:06:51.620 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   01-06 15:06:51.625 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>   01-06 15:06:51.625 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>   01-06 15:06:51.625 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
>   01-06 15:06:51.625 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:    ... 18 more
>   01-06 15:06:51.625 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.TableDocument$Factory
>   01-06 15:06:51.625 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable.readFrom(XSSFTable.java:72)
>   01-06 15:06:51.625 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable.(XSSFTable.java:67)
>   01-06 15:06:51.625 4619-4619/com.etaserve.readxlsx W/System.err:    ... 21 more

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.TableDocument$Factory ` So class  `TableDocument` is missed in your `aa-poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-more-0.1.5.jar`. Reduced to much. Should use a not reduced `jar`?

Comment: I initially tried with jar's available on apache site. they gave me different set of errors. So tried with these.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android. At least `TableDoc‌​ument$Factory` is contained in the pre-built jar.

Comment: Sorry if i sound dumb, i have seen that link. But did not understood how to use it.There are no jar files available on that project, neither gradle dependencies. I will be grateful to know how to use it in my project.